# Validation groups for password change in Symfony 2?

Tags: validation, symfony, symfony-2.1, symfony-forms

I've an issue with validation groups.

When **creating** an user:

- `password` can't be blank
- `password`length should be between 4 and 16 characters

When **editing** an user:

- `password` can be blank
- `password` should be between 4 and 16 characters if it's filled

My user entity validation YAML, declaring the `create` group:

```
My\Entity\User:
  properties:
    username:
      - NotBlank: ~
      - Length: { min: 4, max: 12 }
    email:
      - Email: ~
      - Length: { max: 255 }
    plainPassword:
      - NotBlank:
          groups: [create]
      - Length: { min: 4, max 16 }
```

As far as I know **default** is the group containing all validators to belonging to any group (that is all but `NotBlank` for password). Group `create` contains only the `NotBlank` rule for `plainPassword`. So:

- creating: `default` + `create` groups
- editing: `default` group

I'm passig `array('validation_groups' => array('default', 'create'))` when in my `createAction` controller action, and `array('validation_groups' => array('default'))` when `editAction` is invoked.

It doesn't work: when **editing** the password can be blank (correct) but if it's filled no errors occurs if - say - it's 3 characters long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't the default group supposed to be used as `Default` with capital `D`?

Comment: Don't know but... maybe? Right now it doesn't complain about the the group. I'll try tomorrow at work, thank you for the hint.

Comment: Works, feeling so stupid for the capital letter... thank you!